# AJAX response wraps all the data to JS variable so I can't use HTML attributes on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I made a AJAX call which is working (shows all the requested data in HTML), but I need it to do more. I need HTML attributes to these generated li-elements, example value or href. I can't have them, because they are wrapped to javascript variables.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "controllerURL",
  success: function(response){
        var list = $('#car_list');
        list.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
             var output = "";
             output +="<li><a href=\"#\">" + response[i].name + "</a></li>";
             list.append(output);
             }         
 };
});
```

It will generate all the content to my HTML list:

```
<ul id="car_list">
</ul>
```

But now if I do

```
$('#car_list li').click(function(){
  alert("HELLO!");
});
```

It will never alert, because of javascript variables (at least I think so, JS/jQuery/AJAX is very new to me). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `li` elements are dynamic, so you need to use `.on` and attach the initial selector to your static container that is present on event binding:

```
$('#car_list').on('click', 'li', function(){
```

Comment: Well, that was fast response and easy solution. Thanks!